# Referenced property not a (One|Many)ToOne: in mappedBy of

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I'm pretty new in hibernate. I have to class: User (parent) and Area (child) that are related, User has the FK with Area. I'm doing the hibernate relations but I'm getting error :

> ```
> 2020-05-31 12:39:53.442  WARN  --- [  restartedMain] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered
> ```
>
> during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Referenced property not a
>   (One|Many)ToOne: com.telefonica.npro.model.Area.id_area in mappedBy of
>   com.telefonica.npro.model.User.area

This is USER:

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "NPRO_USUARIOS")
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1330075515340995797L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @NotNull
    @Column
    private int id_usuario;

    @Column
    @NotNull
    private String nombre_usuario;


    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "id_sociedad", cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH })
    private Sociedad sociedad;


    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "id_area", cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH })
    private Area area;

    @Column
    @NotNull
    private String matricula_usuario;


    @Column
    @NotNull
    private String email_usuario;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH })
    @JoinColumn(name="id_perfil")
    private Perfil perfil;

}
```

This is Area:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "NPRO_MAESTRO_AREAS")
public class Area implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1330075515340995797L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @NotNull
    @Column
    private int id_area;

    @NotNull
    @Column
    private String nombre_area;

    @Column
    private LocalDateTime fecha_modif;
    @Column
    private String observaciones;
    @Column
    private int usuario_modif;
    @Column
    @NotNull
    private String activo;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_sociedad")
    private Sociedad sociedad;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_usuario")
    private User user;
}
```

I have no idea what is wrong.. Thanks in advance!

Antonio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mappedBy` should be the field in the related entity that can be navigated back to the current entity. So for `User` , it should be the `user` field in `Area` :

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "NPRO_USUARIOS")
public class User implements Serializable {


     @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH })
     private Area area;
}
```